# There are 8 events that can be scheduled in a week, then find total number of ways that these 8 events are scheduled on exactly 6 days…[CONT]

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There are 8 events that can be scheduled in a week, then find total number of ways that these 8 events are scheduled on exactly 6 days of a week. (Assume arrangement of multiple events on any particular day as immaterial)

I have been struggling with this question for quite some time now. Here is what I managed to do

The events can be distributed in the following ways

$$1+1+1+1+1+3=8$$
And
$$1+1+1+1+2+2=8$$

Now one of the expressions that apparently gets the answer is
$$\left [ \frac{8!}{3!5!} + \frac{8!}{4! (2!)^2 2!} \right]7!$$

Now the expression inside the bracket seems familiar, basically they are trying to distribute the events on various days, but I could still use an explanation for that. I also have no idea why they multiplied by $7!$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two cases.

i) One of the days has $3$ events and each of the remaining $5$ days has an event each.
ii) Two of the days have $2$ events each and rest $4$ days have an event each.

We first make $6$ unordered groups of events. We will assign them to days later.

Number of ways for $i)$ is $ \displaystyle {8 \choose 3} = \frac{8!}{5! \cdot 3!}$.

Number of ways for $ii)$ is $ \ \displaystyle  \frac{1}{2}{8 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2} = \frac{8!}{2^3 \cdot 4!}$

Above, we divide by $2$ as we are making unordered groups at this point.

Now we add $(i)$ and $(ii)$ and order them by multiplying by $7!$ as there are $7$ groups ($6$ with events and one group with no event). If this is not intuitive, we can see it this way - we order $6$ groups with events in $6!$ ways. But we also have $7$ ways to choose the day with no event.

That leads to the answer -

$ \displaystyle \left[ \frac{8!}{5! \cdot 3!} + \frac{8!}{2^3 \cdot 4!} \right] \cdot 7!$

Comment: I didn’t understand the arrangements for case 2. Why is $\binom 62$ there. Also the division by 2 isn’t clear either

Comment: The ${6 \choose 2}$ counts the number of ways to choose $2$ events among the remaining $6$ that are available. The division by $2$ ensures that these selections remain unordered and prevents double counting. If you didn't divide by $2$ you would be assuming the selection $\{E_1,E_4\},\{E_5,E_7\}$ is distinct from $\{E_5,E_7\},\{E_1,E_4\}$.

Comment: @Aditya - I hope Matthew Pilling's comment clarifies.

Comment: very elegant answer

Comment: @MatthewPilling then what is $\binom 82$ about? Is it for selecting 2 events on the same day then and then $\binom 62$ was for selecting two more events that occur on the same day?

Comment: Also that $7!$ part, can it be written is $7P6$ ie. Selecting 6 days out of 7 and permuting them across various events rather than permuting events among days?

Comment: @Aditya yes we choose two groups of $2$ events from total of $8$ events using ${8 \choose 2} {6 \choose 2}$ but as they are ordered we divide by $2$ to make them unordered

Comment: Also yes we can write $7!$ part the way you mentioned too.

Comment: I don’t get how they are ordered. Isn’t combination by definition unordered? Am I using the wrong definition here? Also why do we need to separately select events?

Comment: There are just a lot of conditions to keep track of here :(

Comment: @Aditya yes combinations are unordered - when we select $2$ out of $8$ events, say $(e1, e2)$, they are unordered within. In other words we are not counting $(e1, e2)$ and $(e2, e1)$ separately. But when we do ${8 \choose 2} {6 \choose 2}$ to create two groups of two events each, the groups are ordered. ${8 \choose 2} {6 \choose 2}$ will count both $(e1, e2), (e3, e4)$ and $(e3, e4), (e1, e2)$. But we are only interested in counting one of them as when we multiply by $7!$ to order groups, we will count the other one anyway.

Comment: Ok I thought it was giving an ordered pair of $(e_1,e_2)$. So it is to remove the ordering of events on the two **separate** days which have 2 events in them, but not within the day itself

Comment: @Aditya yes that is correct.

Comment: Also I saw this formula for distributing. Suppose we have $12n$ functions, then no, of distributions is $\frac{12n!}{\frac{(2n)!(2n)!(2n)!(3n)!(3n)!}{2!3!}} * 5!$ for dividing these objects in groups of $2n,2n,2n,3n,3n$. Is this formula correct, and if so, why isn’t the ans matching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128048/discussion-between-math-lover-and-aditya).

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you another approach

Question is obviously disctinct balls into distinct bins , so the exponential generating functions is useful tool for it.

Firstly , lets select which day will not be used ,  we can do it by $C(7,1)=7$ ways.

Now , we have $6$ days and all of them must have at least one event.

Then , the generating function for each day is $$\bigg(x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)$$

Then , what we are looking for is that $$\bigg(x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}\bigg)^6 , \bigg[\frac{x^8}{8!} \bigg]$$ or find the coefficient of $x^8$ and multiply it by $8!$ such that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F2+%2B+x%5E3+%2F+6%29%5E6

We see that the coefficient of $x^8$ is $\frac{19}{4}$ , then $$\frac{19}{4} \times 8! = 191,520$$

Moreover , we have $C(7,1)=7$ ,so the result is $$C(7,1) \times \frac{19}{4} \times 8! = 1,340,640 $$ which is equal to @Mathlover 's answer

MY ADDITION = If the arrangements of the multiple events on any particular day does matter , then we would think the events as identical objects and the question would turn out to be stars and bars question.

We should select fistly that which day will be omited by $C(7,1)=7$ ways. Then , the $8$ events can be dispersed to $6$ different days by $C(2+6-1,2)=21$ ways where all days has at least one events. (Notice that we thought the events as identical objects).

After that , we should multiply by $8!$ to arrange our events. Notice that when we multpily with $8!$ ,we actually determine that which identical event  is which events .For example , let $$*|*|**|*|**|*$$ be one of the distribution and the leftmost objects in the same gap is the first scheluded event. So , the $8!$ will determine that which star is which event.

As a result , $$7 \times 21 \times 8! =5,927,040$$